# object not set to an instance of an object using lambda expression

Tags: linq, lambda

I using lambda expression with where condition to get a count against a addresscollection.
Some of the addresscollection objects have null values to it. For some reason i am getting object not set to an instance of an object. when i dig into the exception, i found return type as {Name = "Boolean" FullName = "System.Boolean"} and return parameter {Boolean}. ANy ideas on how to handle this exception.
Here is my lambda expression that i was using:

```
var codes = (addresscollection.Where(n => n.Code.Contains("A") || n.Code.Contains("S") || n.Code.Contains("Q"))).Count()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either the collection is null or one of the codes is null.

```
var codes = addresscollection == null ? 0 :
            addresscollection.Count(n => n.Code != null && (
                                         n.Code.Contains("A") ||
                                         n.Code.Contains("S") ||
                                         n.Code.Contains("Q")));
```

Comment: in the addresscollection, i have 1000 records out of which some codes are null, but would like to get the count of code which are null and count of code that has A,S,Q.

Comment: Jimmy, thanks a  lot for the reply and it did solve my problem. I am new to the lambda expression. COuld you please explain what the code **addresscollection == null ? 0 :** meant in your reply.

Comment: The ? : is the "IIF" operator in C#. It's a ternary operator, where the first part is the "if" statement, the second is the return value if true, and the third is the return value if false. In this case, it says that if the collection is null, then `codes` will be zero, else it will be the result of the rest of this line.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the line throwing your exception, then either `addressCollection` itself is null, or it contains a null element, or one of the elements contains a null in the `Code` property.

Comment: there are some elements that are null in the addresscollection.

Comment: Then adding on to Jimmy's answer, it'll have to be something like: `var codes = addresscollection == null ? 0 : addresscollection.Count(n => n != null && n.Code != null && (n.Code.Contains("A") || n.Code.Contains("S") || n.Code.Contains("Q")));` This will ensure that the collection itself is not null, and check each element for null, before attempting to look at the code.

Comment: i was wondering what was the difference between **addresscollection.Where(n => n.Code.Contains("A") || n.Code.Contains("S") || n.Code.Contains("Q"))).Count() ** and **addresscollection.Count(n => n != null && n.Code != null && (n.Code.Contains("A") || n.Code.Contains("S") || n.Code.Contains("Q")));**

Comment: For your scenario, assuming you're just dealing with objects, I know there's no difference. I think there might be a difference when you're doing a DB provider for your LINQ - it may generate different SQL, but I'm not even sure there - I'd guess probably not. I've always found the `.Where` to be helpful instead of putting your lambda in `.Count`, but that's just a personal preference. In my comment I started with Jimmy's code, which is why I left it as-is.